# some confusions about [expr.cond#6] statement

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

Because the sections of [expr.cond] are too long,I only cite the section 6 and part of section 7 here,other sections will be given in the link [[expr.cond]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.cond)

> 6.Otherwise, the result is a prvalue. If the second and third operands do not have the same type, and either has (possibly cv-qualified) class type, overload resolution is used to determine the conversions (if any) to be applied to the operands ([over.match.oper], [over.built]). If the overload resolution fails, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, the conversions thus determined are applied, and the converted operands are used in place of the original operands for the remainder of this section.
>
> 7.Lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer standard conversions are performed on the second and third operands. After those conversions, one of the following shall hold:
> 7.1 The second and third operands have the same type; the result is of that type and the result object is initialized using the selected operand.
> 7.2 The second and third operands have arithmetic or enumeration type; the usual arithmetic conversions are performed to bring them to a common type, and the result is of that type.

Let us consider the following situation:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  bool b = true;
  int a = 0;
  auto r = b?'c':a;  //#1
}
```

We know the expression `#1` does not conform to [expr.cond]/2,[expr.cond]/3,[expr.cond]/4,[expr.cond]/5 and we know it's the case of [expr.cond]/6,However only the conditon of **If the second and third operands do not have the same type, and either has (possibly cv-qualified) class type,and overload resolution are successful** is satisfied,then the section 7 would be performed on the operand,as I read the section 6.Obviously,neither `'c'` nor `'a'` are class type.So,I wonder does the section 7 continue to perform on these operand,especially,the section 7.2.If I misunderstand,How the standard make section 7 to performe for case `#1`?

#### Interpretation:

My understanding for sentence 6 as if it's:

```
if("the second and third operands do not have the same type, and either has (possibly cv-qualified) class type" == true){
   if("the overload resolution fails"==true){
       "the program is ill-formed"
   }else{
      "the converted operands are used in place of the original operands for the 
      remainder of this section" //that means sentence 7 will be performed
   }
}
```

Comment: Why did you decide that 7 doesn't apply if the operands are not of class type?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer because,the sentence  after **if* is the condition,if the condition doest not satisfy.then the sentence after the conditon does not perform,I think.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer In other words,my understanding for sentence 6 as if it's:
`if("second and third operands do not have the same type, and either has (possibly cv-qualified) class type"){
  if("overload resolution fails"){
       the program is ill-formed
  }else{
     the converted operands are used in place of the original operands for the 
   remainder of this section
  }
}`

Comment: Your understanding seem correct to me. I don't understand why false "IF" conditions in previous paragraphs didn't stop you from reading further and the condition in the sixth paragraph somehow prevents you from continuing to the seventh paragraph.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Because `true?'c':a` is not the case  the previous paragraphs coverd,so it's the case of sentence 6,because `Otherwise` in sentence 6

Comment: It is not completely covered. From 6, you only get the value category of the conditional expression.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212046/discussion-between-jack-x-and-language-lawyer).

Answer (score 2):

/6 isn’t responsible for “calling” /7; it merely, sometimes, **filters** its inputs by applying certain conversions to the operands (as well as rendering the expression ill-formed in certain cases).  We wouldn’t need “in place of the original operands for the remainder of this section” if we weren’t going to proceed to /7 otherwise.

Comment: If /7 does not performed on these operand in the example I written,How to decide the type of the  result?Or in other words,Does it mean that the rule stopped at /6,and /7 never be performed on `b?'c':a`?

Comment: @jackX: That’s just your question again, which I’ve already answered.

Comment: I don't understand what your meaning,when or what situation do you think  /7 will  perform?

Comment: What I think is,from sentence 2 to sentence 6,if the condition does not satisfy,then `otherwise` will work,the process is step by step,and according to these condtion in previous paragraphs,they are `false`,except the sentence 6,,however it only determin the value category of the result of condition expression,the type of the result have not been determined?It seems to sentence 7 does ,but as the `Interpretation` part,only the condtion in sentence 6 are true,then sentence 7 would be performed,however the condtion is false,It's my question.

Comment: @jackX: /7 applies exactly when neither /2 nor /5 does (and neither /4 nor /6 has rejected the expression).

Comment: @DavisHerring.If process the example as you said,let us analyze them,for example ` b?'c':a; `,2 reject it,3 reject it,4 reject it,obviously,5 reject it,only 6 left ,so `neither /4 nor /6 has rejected the expression` it's not true

Comment: I guess what you want to say is that the /7 does work if both 2 and 5 have rejected the expression,and either 4 or 6 approve the expression ,Right?

Comment: @jackX: By *reject* I mean “determine to be ill-formed”.  In your example they merely do not apply.

Comment: could you change your answers with the interpretation in our comment,It would make your answers more clealy

Comment: @jackX: I’m not sure what would be good to add; this discussion has *expanded* the question, and has mostly been about English anyway.